# findout a chat room by owner ids Mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

I am trying to find out a chat room with two owners (sender and receiver) from DB. if such a chat room is not there one has to be created with ids provided and a name

i am trying to create a chat app with user login and db storage.

```
//Mongoose Schema

const chatRoomSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
room:{
    type: String,
    trim:true,
    required:true
},

owners:[{
    owner:{
        type:mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        required:true,
        ref:'User'
    }
}]

},{
timestamps:true  
})

const ChatRoom = mongoose.model('Chatroom',chatRoomSchema)

//what i tried

const id1 = req.params.id1
const id2 = req.params.id2
let chatroom = ChatRoom.find({owners:{$all:[{owner:id1}, {owner:id2}]}}) 

    if(!chatroom){
        console.log('no chat room')
        chatroom = new ChatRoom({room:'123', owners:[{owner:id1},{owner:id2}]})//creating a new chatroom

          chatroom.save()
         res.send(chatroom)
    }
```

i am trying to find out a chat room with two owner ids. if there is no such chat room we have to create one with both ids as owners

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You want an array of owner ids, not owner objects, so change:

```
owners:[{
    owner:{
        type:mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        required:true,
        ref:'User'
    }
}]
```

to

```
owners:[{
    type:mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    required:true,
    ref:'User'
}]
```

2. you can find room with 2 owners like:

```
var arr = ['5d6bd3b374068124c461975a', '5d6bd3b374068124c4619759']
  ChatRoom.find({owners:{$all:arr}}, (err, room) =>{...}
```

---

full sample project:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const Schema = mongoose.Schema
const init = false

mongoose.connect('mongodb://127.0.0.1/stackoverflow_play5')
//Mongoose Schema

const userSchema = new Schema({
username: String
})

const chatRoomSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
room:{
    type: String,
    trim:true,
    required:true
},

owners:[{
    type:mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    required:true,
    ref:'User'
}]

},{
timestamps:true  
})

const ChatRoom = mongoose.model('Chatroom',chatRoomSchema)
const User = mongoose.model('User',userSchema)

if(init){
  User.insertMany([{username: 'yaya'}, {username: 'hoho'}, {username: 'mil'}], (err, users) => {
    ChatRoom.insertMany([{room: 'r1', owners: [users[0]._id, users[1]._id]}], (err, chatrooms) => console.log('done.'))
  })
}else{
  //ChatRoom.find({}, (err, users)=>{console.log(users)})
  var arr = ['5d6bdfe9c0d0af00ec68932c', '5d6bdfe9c0d0af00ec68932d']
  ChatRoom.find({owners:{$all:arr}}, (err, room) =>{
    console.log(room)
  })
}
```

Comment: @vithushaji note that its a full sample project, so create a blank project and paste this code, to test it (don't put it in your project directly). also for test, set `init = true` in line 3, to create some database datas. and then set it to `init = false`, and replace sample ids in `var arr = ['5d6bdfe9c0d0af00ec68932c', '5d6bdfe9c0d0af00ec68932d']` with ids in your database.

Comment: @vithushaji and also for the second question , you can your own code and change `chatroom = new ChatRoom({room:'123', owners:[{owner:id1},{owner:id2}]})` to `chatroom = new ChatRoom({room:'123', owners:[id1,id2]})`. and also find is async and doesnt return a value, so change `let chatroom = ChatRoom.find` to `let ChatRoom.findOne({condition}, (err, chatroom)=>{console.log('you access chatroom here', chatroom)})`

Answer (score 0):

You can change room to be auto generated by mongoo, and instead of find then create if not found you can use `findOneAndUpdate`

```
const chatRoomSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
room:{
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    auto: true
},

owners:[{
    owner:{
        type:mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        required:true,
        ref:'User'
    }
}]

},{
timestamps:true  
})

const ChatRoom = mongoose.model('Chatroom',chatRoomSchema)

//what i tried

const id1 = req.params.id1
const id2 = req.params.id2
const options = { upsert: true, new: true, setDefaultsOnInsert: true };

let chatroom = ChatRoom.findOneAndUpdate(
            {owners:{$all:[{owner:id1}, {owner:id2}]}}, 
            { owners:[{owner:id1},{owner:id2}]  } , 
            options, function(error, result) {

         if (error) return;

    // do something with the document
});
```

Comment: hi,1)what are options
2) how will the room be auto generated if name of room is not provided.

Comment: It's already mentioned in code, I have changed room type to be object id and auto generated, or you can change it to any type and provide `default: function to generate id `